# Remove substring from each line of text file with regex

Tags: python, regex

Text file (`file.txt`) looks like this:

```
First line.
2. Second line 
03 Third line
04. Fourth line
5. Line. 
6 Line
```

Desired output is 1) eliminating numbers at the beginning of line and 2) remove punctuation:

```
First line.
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Line.
Line
```

I tried:

```
import re
file=open("file.txt").read().split()
print([i for i in file if re.sub("[0-9]\.*", "", i)])
```

But I get results only on word level instead of line level:

```
['First', 'line.', 'Second', 'line', 'Third', 'line', 'Fourth', 'line', 'Line.', 'Line']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fix your current code using

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub("^[0-9]+\.?\s*", "", line.rstrip("\n")))
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4LGclu).

You need to open a file and read it line by line. Then, `^[0-9]+\.?\s*` pattern searches for 1 or more digits (`[0-9]+`) followed with an optional `.` (`\.?`) and then 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) on  each line and removes the match if found.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `re` module in the loop `for`. The possibilities of using regex are many and the `re` module can also be used as a multiline. For example, use the following:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/file.txt', 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
>>> # or use direct value to test in the Python console:
>>> s = """First line.
... 2. Second line
... 03 Third line
... 04. Fourth line
... 5. Line.
... 6 Line"""

>>> s
'First line.\n2. Second line \n03 Third line\n04. Fourth line\n5. Line. \n6 Line'

>>> import re

>>> re.sub(r'[0-9\.\s]*(.*)', r'\1\n', s, flags=re.M)
'First line.\nSecond line \nThird line\nFourth line\nLine. \nLine\n'

>>> re.sub(r'^[0-9\.\s]*(.*)', r'\1', s, flags=re.M)
'First line.\nSecond line \nThird line\nFourth line\nLine. \nLine'
```

Answer (score 1):

The split in this line

```
file=open("file.txt").read().split()
```

splits the file by spaces. Use

```
file=open("file.txt").read().split("\n")
```

instead to split the file by lines.

Comment: Also see https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split to be able to navigate to solutions like this. `str.splitlines()` is also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```py
import re
f = """First line.
2. Second line
03 Third line
04. Fourth line
5. Line.
6 Line"""
print(re.sub(r"(\d{1,2}\.{,1}\s)", "", f));
```

it returns:

```
First line.
Second line
Third line
Fourth line
Line.
Line
```

It don't have to loop through each line.